# Regexp match space or not

Tags: regex

How would I match?

first second

first_second

firstsecond

```
first[\s|_]second
```

matches the first two but how to match the last one as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `?`-quantifier, matching a pattern 0 or 1 times. Please do also note, that `|` loses it's metacharacter function inside a charcater class, there is no need for an alternation inside a character class at all (as it already matches for one of the characters listed).

So your final regex is `first[\s_]?second`

If you only want to match spaces (and not tab or linebreak or any other kind of whitespace), just use `first[ _]?second`